# Visual Studio core features fatal error during installation visual studio 2013 ultimate on windows 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have uninstalled VS 2012 all components and tried to install VS 2013.I have downloaded ISO file fully.I have turned off Firewall,Antivirus and started VS installation as admin.
Still I am getting this error.
[VS installer snap of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Hiw.jpg)

I have seen the log file but could not find how to fix it.
Any Sugestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already tried it after installing .Net Entity Framework 4.5